# Spring Boot Application managed with maven: Error starting ApplicationContext

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have spring boot application that is being managed with maven.No matter which port I choose, the application fails to run giving the following error:

```html
2020-04-23 17:24:16.316  INFO 7684 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-04-23 17:24:16.458  INFO 7684 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-04-23 17:24:16.461  WARN 7684 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-04-23 17:24:16.462  WARN 7684 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 connection adder] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-04-23 17:24:16.464  INFO 7684 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-04-23 17:24:16.467 ERROR 7684 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 8086 was already in use.

Action:

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8086 or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

Comment: try using `server.port=0`

Comment: can you share the code? seems to be something wrong with DB configuration.

Comment: @malverndongeni I get the same message: Web server failed to start. Port 0 was already in use.

Comment: @SandeepKumar It is a large application, I am not sure what I should share: application.properties? pom.xml? or something else?

Comment: Are you working on your personal computer? If every port is busy, you might have the permission issues.

Answer (score 0):

`Web server failed to start. Port 8086 was already in use.`. Your webapp is trying to bind to a network port that is already in use.  Are you running another instance of this or some other application on that port?

Note, a port can only be used by one application at a time.

Comment: No, no other application is running on that port but I have tried several other ports just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Specify your port in your application.properties file

**application.yml**

```yaml
server:
  port: 9080 #e.g.
```

Comment: Thank you for your swift response. This is not a port issue. I have added the port in the application.properties and changed it several times.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue.Apparently my ip changed and I had the previous ip defined in the application.properties (server.address=myIp).

Comment: for a local dev setup, I'd recommend using `localhost` or similar so you're resilient to that.